# Custom UserControl Template with Property-Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, dependency-properties

I created an custom UserControl which includes an Ellipse and a Label. The Label Content and the Color of the Ellipse is binded:
The Binding-Properties are DependencyProperties. 
The color of the Ellipse is depended on the Status, which is a bool (a converter creates the Color)

This is the UserControl1.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Plugin_UPS.Views.UserControl1"
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:WPF_Prism.Infrastructure.Converters.Ups;assembly=WPF_Prism.Infrastructure"
  mc:Ignorable="d"
  x:Name="UC1"
  d:DesignWidth="200" Height="40">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Converters:BoolToColorConverter x:Key="BoolToColorConverter"/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Height="42" Width="504">       
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid Height="Auto" Width="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                          MinWidth="200" MaxWidth="200" MinHeight="35" MaxHeight="40">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Ellipse HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"
                                        Fill="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                                        Height="15"
                                        Width="15"
                                        StrokeThickness="1"
                                        Stroke="Black">
                </Ellipse>
                <Label Content="{Binding Text}" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Margin="0,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" />
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</Grid>

</UserControl>
```

This is the UserControl1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Plugin_UPS.Views
{
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{
    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(UserControl1));


    public bool Status
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(StatusProperty); }
        set { SetValue(StatusProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Status", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1));
}
}
```

This is my UPSViewModel.cs:

```
namespace Plugin_UPS.ViewModel
{
public class UPSViewModel
{      
    public UPSViewModel()
    {
    }

    public string UpsModelText { get { return "Model"; } }

    private bool replaceBatteryCondition; 
    public bool ReplaceBatteryCondition { get { return replaceBatteryCondition; } set { replaceBatteryCondition = value;  } }
 }
}
```

This is my UPSView.xaml:
(here I implement the UserControl1)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Plugin_UPS.Views.UPSView"
         x:Name="UPSUC"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
         xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Plugin_UPS"
         xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:WPF_Prism.Controls.Controls;assembly=WPF_Prism.Controls"
         xmlns:ViewModel="clr-namespace:Plugin_UPS.ViewModel"
         xmlns:Views="clr-namespace:Plugin_UPS.Views"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance ViewModel:UPSViewModel}"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="840" d:DesignWidth="1260">

        <Grid>

            <StackPanel>
                <Views:UserControl1 Margin="10,20,10,10" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Text="{Binding UpsModelText}" Status="{Binding ReplaceBatteryCondition}"></Views:UserControl1>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

But the binding for "Status" and "Text" is not working. 
(Status="True" or Text="Model" is working).

Do you have any ideas what the problem could be? 
Is there a problem with the DataContext?

best regards
Phil

Comment: What is not working exactly? Please explain more. Is this when you change the status? Because we do not implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your viewmodel class.

Comment: The displaying of the Text is not working. I do not Need the NotifyProperty so far. I just want to display the initial value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must not set the UserControl's DataContext to itself, as done by

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

Remove that assignment and write

```
<Views:UserControl1 Margin="10,20,10,10"
    Text="{Binding UpsModelText}"
    Status="{Binding ReplaceBatteryCondition}" />
```

---

Now you'll have to specify the source of the bindings in the UserControl's XAML.

There are multiple ways to do that, one of them is to set the RelativeSource property like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding Text,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" ... />

<Ellipse Fill="{Binding Status,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl},
                Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}" ... />
```

Note that setting `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on the Fill Binding doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot, That's it. It's working perfect. I changed the code in the question too so that you have the correct code.

Comment: I've reverted your edit of the question. The answer wouldn't make sense for the modified question.